# Why GraphLocation.getState returns null?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

`GraphUser.getLocation()` returns `GraphLocation` object. However, all its getter functions like `getState()`, `getCity()`, etc. returns `null`. The debugger shows that it does have data on state, which I am able to retrieve using `getProperty("name")`.

Is this a bug or expected behaviour?

Comment: have you asked fb for location permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for pointing this out, this is definitely a bug. `GraphUser.getLocation()` should return a `GraphPlace` and not a `GraphLocation`.

Please file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

In the mean time, you can re-cast it as a GraphPlace (since they're all proxied anyways), something like:

```
GraphLocation location = user.getLocation();
GraphPlace place = (GraphPlace) location.cast(GraphPlace.class);
```

Comment: I do not see any link or button to create a bug on the link you gave. I can only view existing bugs.

Comment: 1. You need to be signed into facebook. 2. In the "Search bugs or file a new one..." box, start typing, and you'll see a "Create a new bug report" option at the bottom.

Comment: Ok. I was logged in, but never would have noticed that you can create bugs from search box. Worst design ever!